# PHP variable in hidden field carries over as a string literal to the next page

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a small assignment and ran into an issue I can't seem to figure out. The assignment consists of three pages. The first page consists of a simple field that accepts user input. The second page validates that input, and if valid, displays a second input field. The third page validates page 2 input, then adds it to page 1 input.

I've used a hidden field to store page 1 input on page 2, in order to submit it to page 3. But, because page 2 has to display the form only if the previous input is valid, I implemented the form inside a php conditional statement. So, I directly referenced the php variable holding page 1 input as the hidden field value. Here is my page 2 code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["get_number1"] )) {
$number1 = $_POST['get_number1'];
$button_pressed = $_POST['sbmt'];
$message;
$error1 = false;
if ($number1==null) {
    $message = 'ERROR: input field empty';
    $error1=true;
}
else if (!is_numeric($number1)) {
    $message = 'ERROR: input must be numeric';
    $error1=true;            
}
else if (strpos((String)$number1,'.')!=null && strlen((String)$number1)-strpos((String)$number1,'.')>4) {
    $message = 'ERROR: input must contain 0 to 3 decimals';
    $error1=true;
}
else if (!strcmp($button_pressed,"sbmt")){
    $message = 'ERROR: submit button not pressed';
    $error1 = true;
}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GetNumber2.html</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if ($error1==true){
       echo $message .'<br>'. '<a href="GetNumber1.html">Return to Form 1</a>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Your number 1: '.$number1.
         '  <form action="AddNumbers.php" method="post">
            <label>Enter the second number (format : 999999.999) :</label>
            <input type="text" name="get_number2">
            <input type="submit" name="sbmt" value="SubmitNumber">
            <input type="hidden" name="hf_number1" value="$number1";>             
            </form>
         ';
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The next page displays the hidden field value as $number1, even if I remove the quotation marks. Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look up the difference between single quotes and double quotes in PHP and variable expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings with `'` (single quotes) are not parsed.

This means that any variable in `'` will be considered a string.

Use concatenation, for example:

```
$str = '<input type="hidden" name="hf_number1" value="' . $number1 . '">';
```

Comment: That worked! thank you